# How can I change the user owner so a folder created with a PHP script can be edited and/or deleted through FTP?

Tags: php, permissions, ftp, server-configuration

We have a little CMS where we create folders for specific content.
Everything was working fine until we moved to a new server; I noticed that on the new server the "user" from PHP (CMS action) is different from the FTP user. This was not happening before, but now every time a new folder is created through the PHP script it can not be modified through FTP.

I noticed that the owner of the PHP folders is 99 99 which I thing is 'nobody'.

What do I need to do in order for it to work as it was working in the previous server?
On my PHP scripts the permissions are set to 0777 so I really don't know what else to do.

I have access to SSH, WHM and cpanel, maybe there is something inside the PHP settings or APACHE settings that I can modify, maybe straight through WHM.

Please, if there is something to work on the command shell describe it step by step as I mostly know nothing about shell scripting.

This is the code I use in PHP to create my folders:

```
$year_folder = date(Y)."/";
$user_folder = $year_folder."$alias/";
$section_folder = $user_folder."$section/";

//CREATE YEAR FOLDER and persmissions (Forbiden to access directly)
if (!file_exists($year_folder)) {
    mkdir("$year_folder", 0711);// create directory
}

//CREATE USER FOLDER
if (!file_exists($user_folder)) {
    mkdir("$user_folder", 0777);// create directory
}           

    //CREATE CLASS FOLDER
if (!file_exists($section_folder)) {
    mkdir("$section_folder", 0777);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt chown (http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) but it depends on if the server will allow the web server to modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never set a file to 0777. There is never a need for it. If an application tells you to, you should rethink the implementation of said application due to the likelihood of hazardous security flaws.

Which user is Apache running under? Which users need access to this folder?

Secondly, use [chmod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) or [chgrp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php).

Most likely, and one of the safer ways, but not the only way, would be to assign the folder, using [chgrp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php), to the group of the user or users who need access.

If you give read/write access to the owner and group, say, 760, or 770, or alike, and keep the others at 0, you can secure your application while still allowing yourself and others in your group access.

Would you be comfortable editing your PHP CMS script which creates the folder to add the chgrp or chmod command?
**UPDATE**

Instead of creating the directory three times, you can do it once with recursion:

```
$year_folder = date(Y)."/";
$user_folder = $year_folder."$alias/";
$section_folder = $user_folder."$section/";

//CREATE Folder
if (!is_dir($section_folder)) { // changed to is_dir to keep syntax within context
    if(!mkdir($section_folder, 0764, true)){
        echo "Failed to create directory: $section_folder";
    }
}
```

As a debugging step, you can add the following to [check permissions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) after the above code :

```
$perms = fileperms($section_folder);

if (($perms & 0xC000) == 0xC000) {
    // Socket
    $info = 's';
} elseif (($perms & 0xA000) == 0xA000) {
    // Symbolic Link
    $info = 'l';
} elseif (($perms & 0x8000) == 0x8000) {
    // Regular
    $info = '-';
} elseif (($perms & 0x6000) == 0x6000) {
    // Block special
    $info = 'b';
} elseif (($perms & 0x4000) == 0x4000) {
    // Directory
    $info = 'd';
} elseif (($perms & 0x2000) == 0x2000) {
    // Character special
    $info = 'c';
} elseif (($perms & 0x1000) == 0x1000) {
    // FIFO pipe
    $info = 'p';
} else {
    // Unknown
    $info = 'u';
}

// Owner
$info .= (($perms & 0x0100) ? 'r' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0080) ? 'w' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0040) ?
            (($perms & 0x0800) ? 's' : 'x' ) :
            (($perms & 0x0800) ? 'S' : '-'));

// Group
$info .= (($perms & 0x0020) ? 'r' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0010) ? 'w' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0008) ?
            (($perms & 0x0400) ? 's' : 'x' ) :
            (($perms & 0x0400) ? 'S' : '-'));

// World
$info .= (($perms & 0x0004) ? 'r' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0002) ? 'w' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0001) ?
            (($perms & 0x0200) ? 't' : 'x' ) :
            (($perms & 0x0200) ? 'T' : '-'));

echo $info;
```

The above should echo:

```
-rwxrw--r--
```

Comment: yes, no problem, could you explain a bit more how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Copy and paste the snippet of code that creates your folder/file into your question. We can take it from there.

Comment: I added my PHP code to the answer, thanks a lot @sixeightzero